# PHP search script confusion

Tags: php

While building PHP application i have reached the point where i should work on search engine script, however i got few questions about how to.

I have seen many guides and tutorials regarding that matter but none of them explained which method to take.

So options are:

Form with post method which provides posted keywords into function that does query

```
<?php
$keywords = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $_POST['keywords']);
$products->search($keywords);
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="keywords">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Form with get method which alters http address like this `?keywords=x+y+z`, keywords are being passed from $_GET in that case

```
<?php
$keywords = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $_GET['keywords']);
$products->search($keywords);
?>
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="keywords">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Form with post method which upon submit does redirect to the same page but with `?keywords=x+y+z` addon

```
<?php
header('Location: file.php?keywords=' . $_POST['keywords']);
exit();
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="keywords">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<?php
$keywords = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $_GET['keywords']);
$products->search($keywords);
?>
```

From what i have learned pure post method is pretty bad if you want to implement pagination. When switching page via $_GET `?page=2`, post no longer holds and search results are gone, i gather that i would have to switch pages via post as well, so im confused which approach should i conduct, thank you for all the tips:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing a search, the correct method would be a `GET`, [see the description of the various request methods from w3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html). On that base a `GET` is more appropriate then a `POST`.

Having said that, you are retrieving some sort of resource and you could argue that the page is part of this, so either as you seem to propose you can do

```
/search?keywords=HAL&page=2
```

or this uri based version where page is part of the definition of the resource:

```
/search/2/?keywords=HAL
```

Or even go all out as

```
/search/keyword1/keyword2/2
```

(I'm not a fan of the last one per se, I favor the middle or the first; it all has to do with what you define as the resource you are trying to get, and what are the parameters. I'm sure the web is full of discussions that would be rather long-winded to post here)

Realise that you are not talking about `$_GET` vs `$_POST`. these are PHP implementations. You should decide what `METHOD` you will accept as request, and you can then look at those globals to find out where the information lies.

My advice would be to

- read up on those methods (see [the link to w3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html))
- while you're at it, check out [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)

Comment: i see, rather long study ahead of me but i get your point, is there any chance that you could explain at least a bit about how to acomplish that `/search/2/?keywords=HAL` ive seen those slashes around and im curious how to do it ;)

Comment: Those are nothing more then normal slashes in your url bar: they don't have to be equal to a specific file. standard method is to write some sort of 'router' that handles all your traffic (e.g. send all to `application.php` via `.htaccess`. That file reads from the request what the user was asking (e.g. split on `/`). then call the `search.php` file, indicating that page 2 was found, and giving the keywords along with it. Google a bit for `router` in php, together with mvc->lots of examples around!